# EKS Deployment | not able access S3 Bucket via java api but accessible via awscli

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a java spring boot application and im trying to connect to s3 using eks service account

following is service account yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: s3-account
  annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn:  arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/yyyyyy
automountServiceAccountToken: true
```

when i execute the java api to access s3 , i get the following error

> > com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.AWSKMSException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/yyyyyy/aws-sdk-java-1655725004373 is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource: arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:xxxxx:key/dcb9dcc5-0141-4f02-a9e4-bc8a1925e8a1 **because no identity-based policy allows the kms:GenerateDataKey action** (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 95bb5e25-b44b-4087-ba58-fdd7dfbf25e7; Proxy: gateway.zscloud.net)

But if i access via awscli within EKS Deployment it works

> > aws s3 cp new_dir2/new_file2.txt s3://bucket-name/new_file2.txt --region=eu-west-2 --sse aws:kms

What am i missing here ?

Thanks for your response much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Recently, we faced the same issue -- AWS Java SDK v2 failed to access S3 while AWS CLI v2 was able to access the same bucket from within the container.

The following code changes did resolve the issue. The fix essentially was to set the credentials provider explicitly to `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider`.

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
    .credentialsProvider(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create())
    .region(Region.of(region))
    .build();
```